# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "unterstützen" und "befürworten"?

Tags: difference, word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "unterstützen" und "befürworten"?

Beide bedeuten "support" in Englisch. 
Ich habe öfter "befürworten" in Zeitungen gelesen, ist das Wort also formaler?

> Eine allgemeine Helmpflicht für Radfahrer befürworten laut einer Umfrage 41 Prozent der Deutschen.

Könnte man auch "Eine allgemeine Helmpflicht für Radfahrer unterstützen laut einer Umfrage 41 Prozent der Deutschen" sagen? Oder würde das die Bedeutung ein bisschen ändern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Unterstützen* fällt mehr in den Bereich der aktiven Tätigkeit.

Ich kann jemanden *bei der Gartenarbeit unterstützen*, aber nur schlecht ihn *bei der Gartenarbeit befürworten*. (Oder zumindest ändert das den Sinn komplett.)

Wenn man sich die Duden-Eintragungen für [*unterstützen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterstuetzen_beistehen_helfen_entlasten) ansieht:

> - a. jemandem [der sich in einer schlechten materiellen Lage befindet] durch Zuwendungen helfen
>     b. jemandem bei etwas behilflich sein
> - sich für jemanden, jemandes Angelegenheiten o. Ä. einsetzen und dazu beitragen, dass jemand, etwas Fortschritte macht, Erfolg hat

und die für [*befürworten*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/befuerworten):

> [durch Empfehlung] unterstützen, sich für etwas (was man gutheißt)
>   einsetzen

sieht man das auch. *Befürworten* erfolgt also eher nur durch Worte als durch Taten.

Die Bedeutung wird in dem Beispielssatz zwar verändert, aber das nur minimal: Es geht um Politik, und in diesem Fall tun nur wenige Menschen mehr als den Vorschlag zu *befürworten*. Für viele ist dies die maximale Form der Beteiligung an der Politik, daher also auch die maximale Form der *Unterstützung* dieses Vorschlags.

Answer (score 8):

**Befürworten** bedeutet seine Präferenz für etwas aussprechen. Oft ist es eine Alternative für die man sich entscheidet. Siehe auch Duden:

> [durch Empfehlung] unterstützen, sich für etwas (was man gutheißt) einsetzen

Oft ähnelt es "to second" in dieser Redewendung:

> I second her suggestion!
>
> Ich befürworte ihren Vorschlag!

oder "to advocate" hier:

> She advocated higher salaries for doctors.
>
> Sie befürwortete höhere Löhne für Ärzte.

**Unterstützen** dagegen umfasst alle Varianten von "support". Insofern kann man im Beispielsatz auch "unterstützen" einsetzen, verliert aber etwas an Präzision.